# Getting the elapsed time of a mobile connection

Tags: android, telephony

How can I get programatically the elapsed time since the mobile data connection was activated?

I tried to do something like this:

```
    phone = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
    List<DataConnection> dcs = phone.getCurrentDataConnectionList();

    for (DataConnection dc : dcs) {
        if (dc.isActive()) {
            timeElapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - dc.getConnectionTime())/1000;
        }
    }
```

but those methods are not visible from the SDK, so I tried Reflection:

```
    try {
        Class mPhoneFactory = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory");
        Method mMakeDefaultPhone = mPhoneFactory.getMethod("makeDefaultPhone", new Class[] {Context.class});
        mMakeDefaultPhone.invoke(null, this);   

        Method mGetDefaultPhone = mPhoneFactory.getMethod("getDefaultPhone", null);
        Object mPhone = mGetDefaultPhone.invoke(null);

        Method mGetCurrentDataConnectionList = 
            mPhone.getClass().getMethod("getCurrentDataConnectionList", null);
        List<Object> dcs = (List)mGetCurrentDataConnectionList.invoke(mPhone, null);

        Method mGetConnectionTime = 
            dcs.get(0).getClass().getMethod("getConnectionTime", null);
        long getConnectionTime = (Long)mGetConnectionTime.invoke(dcs.get(0), null);         

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The List "dcs" contains the GSMDataConnection that should be there, but the information is not correct, it always says GSM Connections are inactive, that's not true.

Any Idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java clock interface with the [Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html), and subtract the difference between start and end times of the connection.

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I get the start time of the connection?, I cannot find such function in the sdk

Comment: Long begin = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; (at start of method), Long end = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; (at end of method). Then subtract end from begin to get the difference.